# Why does arithmetic left shift of negative number leads to positive number?

Tags: computer-architecture, arithmetic

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Equivalence_of_arithmetic_and_logical_left_shifts_and_multiplication) Wikipedia article, when arithmetic left shift operation is applied to a signed number, the number is multiplied by 2. But there are certain situations where a negative number becomes a positive number when an arithmetic left shift is applied.

Eg.: Take a 2's complement signed integer -5 and 5 bits are used to represent it.

```
11011 ==> -5
10110 ==> -10 (-5x2)
01100 ==> +12 (?)
```

So after two arithmetic left shifts -5 became 24. I expected -20. Why is this the case?

Comment: Please explain how you would store -20 in a 5 bit signed integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$01100 \Rightarrow +12$, not $+24$.

And it is $+12$ because $32-20=12$. With $5$ bits and $2$s complement you can only represent numbers in the range $-16$ to $+15$. You have overflowed this range and, in effect, "run around" to the other end and into the positive number range.